# java.lang.StackOverflowError in clojure tail recursion

Tags: list, loops, clojure, stack-overflow, reverse

I encountered the StackOverflowError for the following code:

```
(defn recursive-reverse
  ([coll] (recursive-reverse [coll nil]))
  ([coll acc]
    (if (= coll '()) acc
        (recur (rest coll) (cons (first coll) acc)))))
```

though using loop would make it work:

```
(defn recursive-reverse [lst]
  (loop [coll lst acc nil]
    (if (= coll '()) acc
        (recur (rest coll) (cons (first coll) acc)))))
```

What goes wrong with the prior code without loop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your bug is here:

```
([coll] (recursive-reverse [coll nil]))
```

You're calling `recursive-reverse` with one argument (a vector). This calls the same argument list of the function, so it does it recursively and creates a stack frame every time.

Change it to:

```
([coll] (recursive-reverse coll nil))
```

and you should be right.

(Also, separate issue, but I would generally do checking for `nil` rather than `'()` and using `next` rather than `rest`. I don't think it has any real advantage in terms of performance or anything, but it seems cleaner to me.)

Comment: `(nil? x)` could be much faster than `(= x ())`, because the compiler can emit just a single bytecode operation, the primitive null check that Java uses. Of course, the latter is pretty quick, but I suspect it's several times slower than the former. As it happens, this optimized nil-check is not implemented (yet?), but it's a reasonable optimization that might be made eventually.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
(defn recursive-reverse
  ([coll] (recursive-reverse coll nil))
  ([coll acc]
    (if (= coll '()) acc
        (recur (rest coll) (cons (first coll) acc)))))
```

You passed the arguments to `recursive-reverse` inside a couple of unnecessary brackets, that's all.